# How to edit decimal number after entered in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I can not edit or re-enter numbers after I typed decimal numbers like `xyxyx.xy` eg: `45682.23` in textbox.

In for example Firefox, I cannot edit the entered value after typing. In Chrome it seems to work

Anyone find an issue in my code?

https://jsfiddle.net/s4ywLapp/56/

```js
$('#decimalNumber').keypress(function(event) {

  if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {

    if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1)) {

    }
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  if (this.value.indexOf(".") > -1 && (this.value.split('.')[1].length > 1)) {
    //alert('Two numbers only allowed after decimal point');
    event.preventDefault();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="decimalNumber" />
```

Comment: Not possible...Please read Question properly

Comment: Your code works as expected in Chrome. What are your issues? I do not understand expected output

Comment: Check it like after entered decimal number (eg. 58586.58) then edit the before dot numbers 58586. you can not edit untill you delete 58 like 5 or 58 like 8. Please check it

Comment: Any specific reason you are not using number field?
<input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control"  />

Comment: mplungjan:- event.which issue i think so can you do without using that. Please use only JavaScript RegExp. Please check in firefox also

Comment: I can edit in chrome all I want

Comment: I see it fails in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap some conditions like the following to allow editing the integer digit

```
//alert('Two numbers only allowed after decimal point');
    if(this.selectionStart > this.value.length - this.value.split('.')[1].length){
          event.preventDefault();

    }
```

However, it is still dirty. you were supposed to right-trim the decimal digits on keypress when 2 digits after the decimal point.